# 404 on extension menu item route in adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, 404

## Update (solution):

The problem seems to come from a difference between my local environment (OS X) which is case-insensitive and my test/live environment (Linux) which is case-sensitive. As the accepted answer indicates, the problem was a capital "R" which should have been a lower case "r" in my controller filename and classname.

I'll keep the question below as-is, in case anyone ends up with the same problem.

---

While this certainly isn't a new question as such, I haven't been able to solve it from the other solutions, so I was hoping someone might give my code a quick look for any immediate errors.

## The problem

I'm trying to create an extension on **Magento 1.8.1.0**, it loads it and adds sub-menu items to the correct place (a sub-menu under Reports with its own items), but when clicking on the menu items I get a **404 page**.

The weird thing is that this only happens on my live server and not on my local copy of the site (i.e. the routes are fine there).

## What have I tried?

Besides having cleared every cache I can think of and logging in and out of the admin panel, I am even currently testing it without cache enabled at all.

I also tried to look at other extensions and changing the XML tag naming, but to no success.

## The files

An overview of the files (the extension is `Codetalk_CustomReports`):

```
Codetalk/
  CustomReports/
    controlllers/
      Adminhtml/
        CustomReportsController.php
    etc/
      adminhtml.xml
      config.xml
    Helper/
      Data.php
```

The `Codetalk/CustomReports/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomReportsController.php` file:

```
<?php
class Codetalk_CustomReports_Adminhtml_CustomReportsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    public function stockoverviewAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('core/text', 'stock-overview')
            ->setText("Stock overview");
        $this->_addContent($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function salesoverviewAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('core/text', 'sales-overview')
            ->setText("Sales overview");
        $this->_addContent($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

The `Codetalk/etc/adminhtml.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <report translate="title">
            <children>
                <Codetalk_CustomReports>
                    <title>Custom Reports</title>
                    <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <stockoverview>
                            <title>Full Stock Overview</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <action>adminhtml/customreports/stockoverview</action>
                        </stockoverview>
                        <salesoverview>
                            <title>Full Sales Overview</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <action>adminhtml/customreports/salesoverview</action>
                        </salesoverview>
                    </children>
                </Codetalk_CustomReports>
            </children>
        </report>
    </menu>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <report>
                        <children>
                            <Codetalk_CustomReports translate="title">
                                <title>Codetalk Custom Reports</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                <children>
                                    <stockoverview>
                                        <title>Full Stock Overview</title>
                                    </stockoverview>
                                    <salesoverview>
                                        <title>Full Sales Overview</title>
                                    </salesoverview>
                                </children>
                            </Codetalk_CustomReports>
                        </children>
                    </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>

</config>
```

And lastly, the `Codetalk/etc/config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codetalk_CustomReports>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Codetalk_CustomReports>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <Codetalk_CustomReports>
                <class>Codetalk_CustomReports_Helper</class>
            </Codetalk_CustomReports>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Codetalk_CustomReports before="Mage_Adminhtml">Codetalk_CustomReports_Adminhtml</Codetalk_CustomReports>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name your controller class `Codetalk/CustomReports/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomreportsController.php` instead of `Codetalk/CustomReports/controllers/Adminhtml/CustomReportsController.php` and change the class name accordingly.

`Codetalk_CustomReports_Adminhtml_CustomreportsController` instead of `Codetalk_CustomReports_Adminhtml_CustomReportsController`

Comment: Oh my God, that worked immediately! Thanks :) Could this have anything to do with a case-sensitive filesystem vs a case-insensitive file system (my local is OS X and test/live is Linux)? Also, I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes when the cooldown is off.

Comment: yes, this is related to case-sensitivity.